# You must add "Use python version 3.x" as the very first task for this pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, installation-package

I am using self hosted agent for the pipeline I am trying to execute. Assuming the name of self hosted agent be "private-hosted-linux-nonproduction". Yaml file has following lines of code.

"
steps:
- checkout: self

```
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          displayName: 'Use Python 3.x'

        - task: riserrad.azdo-databricks.azdo-databricks- 
                configuredatabricks.configuredatabricks@0
          displayName: 'Configure Databricks CLI'
          inputs:
            url: $(databricks_host)
            token: $(databricks_token)
```

"

when pipeline starts executing 'Configure Databricks CLI' task, though I have included python installation as first task I am getting an error with message "You must add "Use python version 3.x" as the very first task for this pipeline. Attached screenshot of the error message.

**However, pipeline execution is successful if I use Microsoft agent pool. It totally works fine. Could anyone suggest what exactly am I missing here?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR7H4.png)

Comment: Refer to the task documentation, which explains how to set it up to work on a self-hosted agent. I don't know why it requires special configuration, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Daniel,

I was trying to set pythonpath, but agent was still considering a different path. So, I had to create symbolic link for the same and it resolved.